# How to rename files to specific string in their filenames

Tags: linux, bash, rename, filenames

I have large amount of .json files that need to be renamed to a specific string of numbers in each file's name. They follow the format:

```
[Artist] Title (Date) [Language][Publisher][Website.####][Pages].json
```

"####" represents a unique numerical ID which I need to rename each file to, ranging from 1-4 characters long. It should look like this:

```
####.json
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. Don't just state the format, provide examples of file names in that format, especially ones that might be difficult to parse correctly (e.g. have `.json` in the middle of the file name instead of at that end, have more than 4 digits in the ID field, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '*\[*.(<->)\]\[*(.json)' '$1$2'
```

Remove the `-n` (dry-run) if happy.

The `zmv` `autoload`able function takes two arguments:

1. a zsh extended glob pattern
2. a replacement specification

It finds the files that match the pattern, here all the non-hidden ones in the current directory that contain in sequence:

- `*` any number of characters (or bytes)
- `\[` a literal `[`
- `*` any number of characters (or bytes)
- `.` a literal `.`
- `<->` any sequence of ASCII decimal digit (`<x-y>` matches on sequences of ASCII decimal digits representing numbers from x to y)
- `\]\[`: `][` literally.
- `*` any number of characters (or bytes)
- `.json`: literally.

In the replacement, `$1` expands to what was matched inside the first pair of `(...)`, so the number matched by `<->` and `$2` to the second (`.json`).

Note that as those `*` match greedly, it will find that number in the rightmost pair of `[...]` whose contents ends in `.<digits>` (excluding the last). For instance in `[a.1][a.2.3][x][y][z].json`, it will extract `3` even though that's not in the second-last pair of `[...]`s.

If that's a problem, you can change it to:

```
zmv -n '*.(<->)\]\[[^][]#\](.json)' '$1$2'
```

Where `[^][]#` matches on 0 or more characters (or non-characters) other than `[` and `]`.

Comment: Is it possible to break down your pattern and explain how it works for people who are less skilled in `zsh`? It took me a long time to discover just what `<->` meant (matching any number). Also, I assume there are corner cases, such as if one of the other fields contains a similar pattern (`.<->\]`).

Comment: @aviro, see edit.